# Acessing to /root folder on BeagleBone (Debian) after /usr directory was deleted

Tags: linux, debian, root, beagleboneblack

I have had some .cpp programs in root directory of my BeagleBoneBlack (Debian). Due to a studpid accident a /usr directory was deleted on my BeagleBone. It make sense for me now, that I can not access the BeagleBone anymore. What I can do is to boot the BeagleBone from SSD-card, but of course I come in this case to another root directory. Do I still have chance to access my .cpp programs from old root directory? The most funniest thing in the story of my stupidness is that I didn't store .cpp programs somewhere else.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, boot a regular [SD-card image](http://beagleboard.org/latest-images) (make sure there is no "flasher" in the image name).

Once booted you can mount the eMMC and access your files. Something like this should do the job:

```
mount /dev/mmcblk1p2 /media
ls /media/root
```

Depending on what you have installed on the eMMC it may be a different partition (last digit) like `mmcblk1p0` or `mmcblk1p1`.
You can then get the files from `/media/root` e.g. via SCP (winSCP if you are on Windows).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! For those who will have the same problem: it is not always the mmcblk1p. In my case the name was mmcbLk1p2. Its better to check firstly the dev directory.

Comment: yes, I left out the partition number on purpose. Should have explained that, sorry. Edited answer to clarify this for anyone who stumbles upon this.